# Can answer-banned users use the "answer your own question" feature?

Tags: support, post-ban, self-answer, instant-self-answer

Can answer banned users use the answer your own question Q&A style feature?

I heard that if you post too many poor answers you can get banned or something, banned from posting answers only, but what if I then check the answer your question Q&A style checkbox and then type an answer, I'd be using the question interface to post an answer, so would the answer ban apply there? is that a bug that needs to be fixed? What will happen?

Comment: as for the "you can get banned or so something" please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: I honestly don't think anyone's tried it out before from a matter of, the people that *usually* get answer banned are *usually* the kind of people who wouldn't be trying to share their wealth of knowledge Q&A style, but I would also presume from a technical perspective that an answer ban would still apply.  You're not banned from asking the question, you'd just be banned from answering it.

Comment: Posting self-answered question is significantly harder than either asking or answering... I would not recommend that as a way to get out of either question or answer ban .

Comment: “so would the answer ban apply there?” - Yes; If you were question banned but wanted to submit an answer to your own question you wouldn’t be able to submit the question. You have to understand question and answer bans are only a result of a continuous pattern of submitting contributions that isn’t well received.  Additionally, once a user is near the ban threshold, that user is warned of that fact.

Comment: *"is that a bug that needs to be fixed?"* - Don't know if it's a bug. If it is, it does not need to be fixed.

Comment: I do not suggest you try to get yourself answer banned to test this!